# iOS Framework target builds, but has build issues when main app target is built

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift

So I have a iOS/Swift application that I have been working on that is using an internal framework called GDDiscoveryShared. I can build the framework target fine, but when I try to build the main app target, all of a sudden, the XCode generated header for the GDDiscoveryShared framework starts having issues, not being able to find some ObjC classes in the GDDiscoveryShared framework. Here are the build errors:

```
<unknown>:0: error: /Users/jneugass/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GDDiscovery-bosotkikojgkrbgtkkkbwmokbbvr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GDDiscoveryShared.framework/Headers/GDDiscoveryShared-Swift.h:62: cannot find protocol declaration for 'GDObjectMappingProtocol'
<unknown>:0: error: /Users/jneugass/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GDDiscovery-bosotkikojgkrbgtkkkbwmokbbvr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GDDiscoveryShared.framework/Headers/GDDiscoveryShared-Swift.h:82: expected a type
<unknown>:0: error: /Users/jneugass/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GDDiscovery-bosotkikojgkrbgtkkkbwmokbbvr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GDDiscoveryShared.framework/Headers/GDDiscoveryShared-Swift.h:88: cannot find protocol declaration for 'GDObjectMappingProtocol'
<unknown>:0: error: /Users/jneugass/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GDDiscovery-bosotkikojgkrbgtkkkbwmokbbvr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GDDiscoveryShared.framework/Headers/GDDiscoveryShared-Swift.h:92: expected a type
<unknown>:0: error: /Users/jneugass/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GDDiscovery-bosotkikojgkrbgtkkkbwmokbbvr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GDDiscoveryShared.framework/Headers/GDDiscoveryShared-Swift.h:97: cannot find protocol declaration for 'GDObjectMappingProtocol'
<unknown>:0: error: /Users/jneugass/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GDDiscovery-bosotkikojgkrbgtkkkbwmokbbvr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GDDiscoveryShared.framework/Headers/GDDiscoveryShared-Swift.h:103: expected a type
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'GDDiscoveryShared'
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'GDDiscoveryShared'
```

The GDObjectMappingProtocol is definitely a located in the GDDiscoveryShared framework, so I am not quite sure what the heck is going on.